# How to make slides change automatically on slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I have added a Jquery slider (called SudoSlider) to my website, with 'previous' and 'next' buttons that allow users to advance to the next slide, or go back one. I would, however, like to make it so that the slides change automatically.

I have come across questions that are similar to this, but my Javascript is rather limited and so I'm unable to use the codes given to other users.

If anybody can help me achieve this I would be very grateful.

Please see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DanCUK89/VN7F8/) here for the codes used.

Also, the slider can be seen in action [here](http://tinyurl.com/cafzwoz) if the JSFiddle is of no use.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/VN7F8/1/

I just changed the sequence of loading javascript. Below is the complete HTML with javascript included & include external css u have.

HTML Changes:

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/jquery/slider/js/jquery.sudoSlider.min.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){    
            var sudoSlider = $("#slider").sudoSlider();
     });    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul>                
                <li>
                    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;height:300px;">
                        <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/final_slide_6.png" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div style="margin:0 auto;width:620px;height:300px;background:url('http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/final_slide_5.png');">

                    <div class="product_row_1">
                        <div class="one">
                        <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Sennheiser_SKP_300_G3--product--1091.html" class="slide_product_name">Sennheiser SKP 300 G3</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Sennheiser_SKP_300_G3--product--1091.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/skp300.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" />
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£296.00</p>
                             <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="two margin-3">
                         <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Fostex_PM841_Professional_Studio_Monitor--product--1110.html" class="slide_product_name">Fostex PM8.4.1</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Fostex_PM841_Professional_Studio_Monitor--product--1110.html""><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/pm841.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" />
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£412.50</p>
                           <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="three margin-3">
                         <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Delkin_Wingman_HD_3oz_Waterproof_Action_Camera--product--850.html" class="slide_product_name">Delkin Wingman</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Delkin_Wingman_HD_3oz_Waterproof_Action_Camera--product--850.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/wingman.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <div class="4stars"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" /></div>
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£179.19</p>
                            <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="product_row_2">
                        <div class="one">
                        <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Street_Runner_Bundle--product--1104.html" class="slide_product_name">D|Focus Street Runner Kit</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Street_Runner_Bundle--product--1104.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/streetrunnerbundle.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <div class="4stars"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" /></div>
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£332.50</p>
                            <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="two margin-3">
                         <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Field_Runner_Bundle--product--1105.html" class="slide_product_name">D|Focus Field Runner Kit</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Field_Runner_Bundle--product--1105.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/fieldrunnerkit.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <div class="4stars"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" /></div>
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£382.50</p>
                             <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="three margin-3">
                         <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Austin_Rig_Bundle--product--1106.html" class="slide_product_name">D|Focus Austin Rig Bundle</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Austin_Rig_Bundle--product--1106.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/austinrigbundle.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" />
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£499.17</p>
                            <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    </div>
                </li>    
            <li>
                    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
                        <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/final_slide_3.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
                        <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/final_slide_4.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: How did you fix it? What did you change? If jsfiddle ever goes down, we will never know how you fixed it

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I'd extremely grateful. Is it possible to make each slide slide-in from the right, rather than fade? I apologise for having rather limited Javascript.

Comment: @SVS Thanks a lot, sorry my response was supposed to be to the top answer. Thanks a lot for your tweak. 
I managed to edit the slider's parameters. I've managed to make it slide continuously, and set the slide time/pause time. Please see this http://www.jsfiddle.net/DanCUK89/L7eHa/ JSFiddle for the most recent version. I am hoping to make it so that it slides back (quickly) through the slides to go back to the first slide once it reaches the last one. Also, if a visitor clicks a prev/next button, the auto-sliding function seems to stop. Thanks in advance everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it sets the slider to automatically change.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){    
        var sudoSlider = $("#slider").sudoSlider({fade: true,auto:true});
    });
```

here is the [working link](http://jsfiddle.net/VN7F8/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers so far, very much appreciated. I managed to use @Furqan's reply to get an idea of how to edit the slider's parameters. I've managed to make it slide continuously, and set the slide time/pause time. Please see this [link]http://jsfiddle.net/DanCUK89/L7eHa/[/link] JSFiddle for the most recent version.

I am hoping to make it so that it slides back (quickly) through the slides to go back to the first slide once it reaches the last one.

Also, if a visitor clicks a prev/next button, the auto-sliding function seems to stop.

Thanks in advance everybody!